# How to enter to recovery mode in Eurostar epad genie tablet

Tags: tablet, android-versions

How to enter to recovery mode in Eurostar epad genie tablet. i tried to enter to recovery mode using the key combination power button and volume + button. When i press those button it shows FASTBOOT mode and I cannot enter into recovery mode. Please help me

Comment: Did you also try `Power`+`Volume-`?

Comment: yes. Its just booting normaly.

Comment: OK and I assume you also tried both Volume buttons plus Power?  Some devices (even touch devices) will also involve the `Home` button, so try that too.  You can also try putting your device in Developer mode and trying `adb reboot recovery` or, while it is in fastboot mode, `fastboot reboot recovery`.

Comment: there is no home button in my tab and also my tab pattern locked, I forget my pattern so i cant put the device in developer mode.